# what does the mongoosejs output safe:undefined mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a collection using mongoosejs

```
var LogSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, index: true, required: true },
    message: { type: String, required: true },
    device: { type: String  }
    },
    { capped: 100000 }
);
```

and am getting this message printed out whenever it runs

```
Mongoose: logs.ensureIndex({ name: 1 }) { background: true, safe: undefined }
```

I can't find the documentation that explains what the safe means. Can someone point me to the mongo or mongoose docs?

Comment: Why do you have the string as an array for the name?

Comment: Thank you Nagasimha, I just fixed it. However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: If you remove index:true does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does. Any thoughts as to why? Also, do you know what {safe: undefined} means?